# Put array of values in a single column spread over different rows and then repeat for next column

Tags: excel, matlab

I am asking about writing to an Excel sheet from MATLAB.

I want to put array of values in a single column and when all the values are placed in the cells in a vertical fashion then I would like to move to the next column and again put all the values.

Answer (score 0):

I will give short example:

```
x= [ 1 2; 3 4]
pth = 'C:\data\tst1.xls'
Ncol = size(x,1)
for i=1:size(x,2)
  xlswrite(pth,x(1,:)',['A1:A' num2str(Ncol)]);
  xlswrite(pth,x(1,:)',['B1:B' num2str(Ncol)]);
end
```

of course, if your number of columns is less than 26, you could
save cell names in array and index it within for loop, so that *xlswrite* needs to be written once.